# How do I update compatibility.js in firefox? Referencing to PDF.js

Tags: javascript, firefox, pdf.js

I have the problem a lot of people have where the permission is denied in firefox to call the print method of a window. I've done a lot of searching and people say they can get past this by updating their compatability.js, only I can't find any post saying how to do this.

Edit: I get the error "Permission denied to access property print", I know this can be fixed by disabling pdf.js but then I print a blank page.

Comment: Um, are you talking about pdf.js? https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/web/compatibility.js What is the code you are trying to actually run?

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about pdf.js not giving me permission to call the print method of a window, in my case an iframe. When clicking the print button the print windows of the browser should open with the pdf ready to be printed, it does this on all browsers except for Firefox. People say this can be fixed by updating compatibility.js.

Comment: So you should include pdf.js in your question so people know that is what you are talking about.

Comment: You're right! You know how to help me?